# how do i check for a string occurence in input data

Tags: php, string

I want to check for occurence of a particular string in user input data.
How do I do it.
Here's my code:

```
    <?php
    $data = $_POST["data"];

    if (strcmp("123",$data))
       echo "string matches";
    else if (strcmp("234",$data))
       echo "string 2 matches";
    else 
       echo"string does not match";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check to see if `$_POST['data']` **contains** the strings you're searching for, do this:

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST["data"];

    if (strpos($data, "123") !== false)
       echo "data contains 123";
    else if (strpos($data, "234") !== false)
       echo "data contains 234";
    else 
       echo "data does not contain either";
```

But, if you want to check for an exact match, you'd just do:

```
<?php
    //...

    if ($data == "123")
       echo "data is equal 123";
```

Check out the [manual](https://secure.php.net/strpos) for `strpos()` for more information. For a case-insensitive search, you can use `stripos()` (`i` for "insensitive") instead.

Checking for strict equality with `false` is important. If the match begins at the first character in the string, it will return `0`, which indicates a match. You need `!==` to distinguish `0` from `false`.

Comment: just says data does not contain either @will

Comment: Does it? What does `var_dump($_POST["data"]);` show?

Comment: @RahulSharma you need to ppopulate your $_POST data,you need to fill in a form to send the data to the page. Will, this is the correct answer +1. Especially with the clarification of `false` .

Comment: Awesome, thanks Rahul and thanks @Martin, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    <?php
        //$data = isset($_POST["data"])?$_POST["data"]:'';
        $data = "12356789";
        if (strpos($data, "123")!== false){
           echo "string matches";
        }
        else if (strpos($data, "234")!== false){
           echo "string 2 matches";
        } else {
           echo"string does not match";
        }
?>
```

Comment: You have the parameters reversed here. It's `strpos($haystack, $needle, ...)`.

Comment: it didn't work. keeps on saying string does not match @sanjeev shetty

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST["data"];

if (strcmp("123",$data) === 0)
   echo "string matches";
else if (strcmp("234",$data))
   echo "string 2 matches";
else 
   echo"string does not match";
?>
```

Comment: @Will er, this answer uses `strcmp`, not strpos.

Comment: Ah, sorry, oversight! Another answer did switch the needle and haystack, and I guess I mis-skimmed :) I still believe he wanted to "search" rather than "compare", though.